# Justifying term-by-term anti-differentiation of a real analytic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I have a real analytic series $f(x) = \sum c_n x^n$ (centered at zero for simplicity) convergent on $|x| < R$, and if $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$ on $(-R, R)$ then is it true that $F(x) = C + \sum \frac{c_n}{n+1} x^{n+1}$ for $|x| < R$?

In other words, what is necessary to justify the term-by-term anti-differentiation of the power series of $f$? Just the convergence of the new series in the same open interval? For one thing, we know that $f$ is integrable since it is differentiable/continuous.

Comment: The locally uniform convergence of the series for $f$ guarantees that the interchange of summation and integration in $$F(x) = F(0) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = F(0) = \sum c_n \int_0^x t^n\,dt$$ is legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. That's because you can exchange integration and uniform limits on compact intervals $[a, b]$ and power series converge locally uniformly on $(-R, R)$, which means just that.